# Which package contains the C standard library?

Tags: programming, package-management, source-code

Which package contains the C standard library?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should be available in the [glibc package](https://launchpad.net/glibc) Though most all the packages essential to development and code-building can be found in [build-essential](https://launchpad.net/build-essential)

Comment: build-essential is actually a dummy package, which has dependencies on "all you need to make a build". Very usefull, as you seldom know about all the libraries you'll actually need when building your applications from sources. But overkill if you only need the glibc.

Answer (score 2):

The package name is libc6, if you are trying to build a C app then you will want to install the build-essential package which brings the development packages.

Comment: I'll add that the source package's name in recent Ubuntu versions is `eglibc` as seen at http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=sourcenames&keywords=eglibc.

Answer (score 1):

It's `libc6` / `libc6-dev`. For cross compilation for 64 bit / 32 bit systems, you can install `libc6-amd64` `libc6-dev-amd64` or *i386 repsectively.

The `-dev` packages are the ones that contain `/usr/include/stdlib.h`.

Comment: To clarify, although it isn't succinctly apparent from the package description, the host-native packages are `libc6` & `libc6-dev` for either i386 or amd64.  For cross-compilation, i386 uses `libc6-*amd64`, and amd64 uses `libc6-*i386`.

Comment: Daniel is right: libc6-amd64 (and its 'dev' version) are usefull only for cross-compiling from i386. Whatever your platform, if you want to build for the same platform, you only need libc6/libc6-dev.

Comment: Edited the answer accordingly. That's quite important sorry I missed it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can find which package a file belongs to using the command:

`dpkg-query -S /path/to/file`

In this case, this does depend on you first knowing which file is the C standard library: /lib/libc6.so.6